# Why wordpress multisite root site showing blog prefix by force?

Tags: permalinks, multisite

I have installed a directory base multisite in the localhost and create two subsites. The URL's are looking like as follows:

- Root Site: `http://localhost/mcqacademy/`
- Subsite for English: `http://localhost/mcqacademy/en/`
- Subsite for Bangla: `http://localhost/mcqacademy/bn/`

Now I am thinking to update the permalinks. I opened the permalinks page in the root site (http://localhost/mcqacademy/wp-admin/options-permalink.php)

Problem is I don't understand why the URL structure is showing like `http://localhost/mcqacademy/blog/` instead of `http://localhost/mcqacademy/`

**Note:**
When I am in the root site theme and use the following code:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$url = get_author_posts_url( $user_id );
```

Return me the `http://localhost/mcqacademy/blog/author/admin/` url.

I think the URL should be `http://localhost/mcqacademy/author/admin/`.

On the other hand, When I am in the `en` subsite theme and use the following code:

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();
$url = get_author_posts_url( $user_id );
```

Return me the `http://localhost/mcqacademy/en/author/master/` url.
Which is the expected output!!

Thanks in Advance! Let me know your suggestions ...

Answer (score 2):

Got a solution at - `https://isabelcastillo.com/remove-blog-slug-multisite`

In the root site of my directory base multisite, I went to `Settings -> Permalinks`.

Then I change my permalink.

Then go the Network Admin -> Sites -> and clicked on Edit

Then switched to `Settings` tab -> Now remove the `blog` text from `Permalink Structure` and saved.

This is not recommended. If you do this on the main site of your network, you must make sure that none of your posts, categories, or tags have a slug equal to the slug of a subsite. That would cause a conflict.